# how we can compute the training time of deep neural networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am currently working on a deep neural network, but i am confused about how we can compute the training time of a deep neural network. How i will know that my neural network takes less time compared to other deep neural networks.

I am looking forward to your help and any article recommendation.

Comment: Are you refering to the time required for training the model of for doing one prediction once trained. Comparing training time between models does not really make sense because the time depends on the size of the database you use and complexity of the model itself. For instance deep convolutionnal network training heavility depends also of the processing capability of your GPU

Comment: So the training time of neural network model depend on GPU ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- If you are using a jupyter notebook or any notebook using a .ipynb file then you can use the: `%%time`, to calculate the time to run the cell.
- If you are planning to use a .py code and just want to calculate the time the code runs you can utilise the `time` library before and after the training portion of the code, you could use the following method

`from time import time
start = time()
"Your code"
print(time()-start)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I follow the same code which you mentioned. My neural network take approximately 20 minutes to train the neural network on 200 epochs.  My question is that, my model take 20 minutest to train on large dataset. So how i can define my training time, that my neural network take less time due to simple architecture or something else.

Comment: I don't think you can define the neural network training time if you need a certain accuracy level, the easiest way would be to use fewer epochs or a callback function which stops the training once the network hits a predefined accuracy level. Else, the method would be to use a better GPU support.

Comment: so the training time of neural network we can't define it.

Comment: No, if you don't want to give up on the accuracy.

Comment: So, how i can define my training time. That my neural network training time is supposed 2 minutes to train the 1000 samples compare to other neural networks.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison of ML Models shouldn't be on the basis of training time, as time taken can differ on many factors:

> 1. Same code show variable time taken when ran several time, depending upon instantaneous CPU load and performance.
> 2. Size of Dataset taken to train the model.
> 3. Some other factors too, like no of neural network layers, no of neurons in each layer, complexity of activation function used, etc.

But if you're using Multi-Threading / Multi-Processing to train your model, and want to know if that is helping or not, you can use timing functions provided by python.

### 1. Using perf_counter() from time module

```
from time import perf_counter, sleep

start = perf_counter()
# Some Code
end = perf_counter()

print(f"Time taken to execute code : {end-start}")
```

[image: Output]

### 2. Using %%time in .ipynb notebooks

```
%%time
# Some Code
```

[image: Output]