# Measure Inference Time of Deep Neural Networks in tensrflow/ keras

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, inference

I would like to estimate the inference time in a neural network using a GPU/cpu in tensprflow /keras  . Is there a formula/code that gives you the inference time knowing the FLOPs of the Neural Network, the number of Cuda Cores / cpu  and the frequency of the cpu/GPU ? Does a similar formula exists for training time ?

Are there other cpu/GPU caracteristics that matters in estimating inference or training time ?

Is it reasonnable to estimate that running an inference on a GPU that has 4000 CUDA cores goes twice faster than on a GPU with only 2000 CUDA cores ?

I read this article, it explained very well, but I don't know how to use it in tensorflow?

https://towardsdatascience.com/the-correct-way-to-measure-inference-time-of-deep-neural-networks-304a54e5187f

[how we can compute the training time of deep neural networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70462682/how-we-can-compute-the-training-time-of-deep-neural-networks)

Answer (score 0):

There is no formula for calculating inference time based on FLOPs, GPU cores, parameter numbers and so on. Inference time will likely depend on a range of factors, such as how easy it is for the model to be parallelized, whether there are any bottlenecks in computation, etc. For example, doubling the number of GPU cores will only reduce inference time if the number of cores was the bottleneck in computation.

Instead, you should measure the inference time directly, using something like the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

net   = tf.keras.models.load_model("pretrained_model.keras")
ds    = get_dataset(...) # function for loading a dataset

ds    = iter(ds)

# Run a few iterations to make sure everything is loaded into memory
for _ in range(10):
  net.evaluate(next(ds),verbose=0)

times = []
N     = 100

for _ in range(N):
  sample = next(ds)
  start_time = time.time()
  net.evaluate(sample,verbose=0)
  end_time = time.time()
  times.append(1000*(end_time - start_time))

print(f"Model       : {net.name}")
print(f"Iterations  : {N}")
print(f"Average (ms): {np.mean(times)}")
print(f"Std dev (ms): {np.std(times)}")
print(f"Min (ms)    : {np.min(times)}")
print(f"Max (ms)    : {np.max(times)}")
```

Diclaimer: I'm not sure if this is the best way, but could not find much information online about correctly measuring inference time in keras/tensorflow. If you call keras.model.evaluate with verbose set to 1, then the output will include a time per step, which in my experience is lower than the time calculated by the above code.